# Single jpa @Query to return true/false when count in one table is equal to column value in other table

Tags: jpa, select, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 entities: Leaflet and Page with One to Many relation (many Pages per Leaflet)

```
@Entity
Leaflet {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private UUID leafletId;
 private Integer noPages;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "leaflet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 Set<Page> pages = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity 
Page {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 private UUID pageId;
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "leaflet_id")
 private Leaflet leaflet;
 @Enumerated
 private PageStatus status = PageStatus.CREATED;
}
```

and status enum

```
public enum PageStatus {
CREATED,
FRAMED
```

}

I would like to write single query to return whether all Pages for given Leaflet are already FRAMED. So I wrote this

```
@Repository
public interface PageRepository extends JpaRepository<Page, UUID> {

@Query("SELECT case when (COUNT(p) = l.noPages) then true else false end from Page p inner join Leaflet l on p.leaflet.leafletId = l.leafletId  where p.status = 1 and l.leafletId = ?1")
    boolean allPagesFramed(UUID leafletId);
}
```

but error comes which means I cannot use l.noPages directly

> ERROR: column "leaflet1_.no_pages" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Is there a way to make it 1 query ?
Of course, I can first select l.noPages with first hit to DB, then inject this value to above query (instead of join) which I'm doing right now as workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this based on page table. With nativeQuery = true

```
@Query(value = "select case when ( count(*) > 0 ) then false else true end " +
                "from page p " +
                "where p.leaflet_id = ?1 and p.status <> 1 ", nativeQuery = true)
boolean allPagesFramed(UUID leafletId);
```

If a page has at least one status different from 1 (FRAMED), then the query return false, not all the pages are FRAMED.

Comment: hi José, thanks for your answer. It was a clever way to inverse the counting condition, I did not think of it. It worked like a charm. 
It also worked with my jpql query. Unfortunately I cannot give you vote up due too low reputation